# "403","message":"Feature level access has been denied"

Tags: here-api

I have a valid Here licence and I have been using it for long time. Suddenly I had the above response from server.
The url is: http://pde.api.here.com/2/matchroute.json?app_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&app_code=xxxxxxxxxxxx&routemode=car&file=&regions=WEU&release=LATEST

```
    def connectPost(self, url, data, headers=None):
    return self.S.post(url, data=data, headers=headers , proxies = self.proxy_dict)
```

Comment: what should be the `file` parameter value?

Comment: @Tomas response = self.connectPost(url, self.tmp_route_data, headers={"Content-type": "text/csv"})

Comment: self.tmp_route = str(latitude,longitude
50.875182,4.499943
50.875240,4.499935
50.875302,4.499920
50.875375,4.499893
50.875450,4.499854
50.875527,4.499799
50.875602,4.499728
50.875670,4.499643)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the licensing, and delivery back-end system The account has expired that's why.

Cheers,
WaliedCheetos

Comment: Is matchrouting included in enterprise account

Answer (score 0):

Try please this python code(it works properly for me)

```
# Hello World program in Python
import requests
import json

data = bytes("\n".join([
  'LATITUDE,LONGITUDE',
  '50.875182,4.499943',
  '50.875240,4.499935',
  '50.875302,4.499920',
  '50.875375,4.499893',
  '50.875450,4.499854',
  '50.875527,4.499799',
  '50.875602,4.499728',
  '50.875670,4.499643'
]), 'utf-8')

url = 'http://pde.api.here.com/2/matchroute.json?app_id=xxxx&app_code=xxxxx&routemode=car&regions=WEU&release=LATEST'
resp = requests.post(url, data)
parsed = json.loads(resp.text)
print(json.dumps(parsed, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

[This code in on playground](https://repl.it/@UserHuman/HummingWittyNetbsd)

Comment: I tried the code with my valid credentials at the site you sent me but still getting the sane error.
    "faultCode": "se1a7c3f6-e8d5-432c-8ceb-2b958fd3d951",
    "message": "Feature level access has been denied",    "responseCode": "403"

Comment: Is matchrouting included in enterprise account